# How to tell maven to use a snapshot version? It tries to load x.y.z-SNAPSHOT but nexus has replaced -SNAPSHOT

Tags: java, maven, nexus

We use a nexus repository for our libraries. Another projects has it as a dependency in version 6.1.2-SNAPSHOT, but maven fails to fetch it.

It tries to fetch https://nexus/nexus/repository/snapshots/tld/company/lib/lib-6.1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar but it fails.
When checking manually I can see that there is a https://nexus/nexus/repository/snapshots/tld/company/lib/lib-6.1.2-20220101.111111-11.jar available.

My settings.xml has a repository entry for the snapshots:

```
        <repository>
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <url>https://nexus/nexus/repository/snapshots</url>
          <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
```

How do I tell Maven to use that instead?

Comment: How did you put the snapshot in your nexus?

Comment: Is the library that requires the snapshot a snapshot itself? If not that might be the reason as depending on a snapshot has a couple of risks, e.g. compatibility, security etc. - thus a "release" version should only depend on a defined version (or a range of version) of a dependency. Nexus might be enforcing that.

Comment: SNAPSHOT just tells maven to pick the latest snapshot version (depending on your repo, you could keep the last N snapshot version). Maven reads the file `maven-metadata.xml` from the repository (it shoult be on the same folder as the jar files) and one of the properties references the latest snapshot which is versioned in the way you shared (name-version-timestamp-index). Check the medatadata file as it might be corrupted. As an example, check this [snapshot repo](https://repo.spring.io/ui/native/snapshot/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.3.9-SNAPSHOT) from spring.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen it is done via Jenkins or Azure DevOps. I have no insight in that.

Comment: @Thomas yes, both are snapshots.

Comment: @Augusto but why does Maven with `-X` says it tries to load t tries to fetch https://nexus/nexus/repository/snapshots/tld/company/lib/lib-6.1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar instead of https://nexus/nexus/repository/snapshots/tld/company/lib/lib-6.1.2-20220101.111111-11.jar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the issue was resolved.

We had a "clean snapshots task" in Nexus which deleted "old" -- although this one was not that old -- snapshots. We changed the number of kept snapshots and restored the ones missing.

Thanks so far for all suggestions!

Comment: LOL, I get this issue on most places I've worked after the Christmas / new year holidays (which looks it might have been the same problem :D)

Comment: Great... I get the intention but finding out what the issue was, was not that easy since I have limited access to Nexus, thus I thought it must be an issue on my machine. Thankfully we got that resolved. :)